# How to find out what colours items in editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, colors, editor, resharper

From time to time I have hard while when I try to change color of some item in Visual Studio. E.g. I'd like to see my `/// <reference path="... />` lighter, because I use dark background.

How can I find appropriate rule in `Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display Items` that sets the color. It's more difficult because I use Resharper which comes with its own rules. I can imagine that there are even more extensions with their rules.

So, is there any means how to do it? Some useful plugin? Any option in VS menu?

Comment: It might be a stupid question but I will ask anyway :-) Have you tried changing Display items -> Comment? Unfortunately that will change all comments, not just ones for reference path.

Comment: I'd like a general approach. Anyway thanks for stopping by :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. My colours have changed a lot recently due to upgrading to 2012. I found this which might help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545.aspx